# confusion in xslt creation on output method

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm writing a XSLT and ran it in java. I'm using `Saxon`. When I run my program, I got the below Exception.

```
Error at xsl:value-of on line 314 of chapters.xsl:
  SERE0014: Illegal HTML character: decimal 157
  at xsl:call-template name="entry" (file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl#417)
  in built-in template rule
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl#385)
     processing /chapter/section[1]/section[5]/table[1]/tgroup[1]/tbody[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl#370)
     processing /chapter/section[1]/section[5]/table[1]/tgroup[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl#205)
     processing /chapter/section[1]/section[5]/table[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl#205)
     processing /chapter/section[1]/section[5]
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl#61)
     processing /chapter/section[1]
  at xsl:apply-templates (file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl#19)
     processing /chapter
; SystemID: file:///C:/Users/u0138039/Desktop/Proview/HK/2016/COMPORD/final/XSLT/chapters.xsl; Line#: 314; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Illegal HTML character: decimal 157
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.HTMLEmitter.writeEscape(HTMLEmitter.java:366)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.XMLEmitter.characters(XMLEmitter.java:594)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.HTMLEmitter.characters(HTMLEmitter.java:428)
    at net.sf.saxon.serialize.HTMLIndenter.characters(HTMLIndenter.java:255)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.characters(ProxyReceiver.java:194)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.characters(ProxyReceiver.java:194)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.characters(ProxyReceiver.java:194)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ProxyReceiver.characters(ProxyReceiver.java:194)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.ComplexContentOutputter.characters(ComplexContentOutputter.java:174)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ValueOf.processValue(ValueOf.java:295)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.SimpleNodeConstructor.processLeavingTail(SimpleNodeConstructor.java:222)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ValueOf.processLeavingTail(ValueOf.java:280)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.AnalyzeString.processLeavingTail(AnalyzeString.java:443)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:336)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates$ApplyTemplatesPackage.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:516)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1061)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:284)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:244)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.expand(Template.java:367)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.CallTemplate.process(CallTemplate.java:343)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ForEach.processLeavingTail(ForEach.java:419)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:336)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.TextOnlyCopyRuleSet.process(TextOnlyCopyRuleSet.java:65)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1100)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates$ApplyTemplatesPackage.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:516)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1061)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:284)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:244)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:336)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:284)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:244)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:336)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:284)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:244)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:336)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:284)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:244)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:336)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.apply(ApplyTemplates.java:284)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ApplyTemplates.processLeavingTail(ApplyTemplates.java:244)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Instruction.process(Instruction.java:144)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:450)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.ElementCreator.processLeavingTail(ElementCreator.java:389)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Block.processLeavingTail(Block.java:669)
    at net.sf.saxon.expr.instruct.Template.applyLeavingTail(Template.java:336)
    at net.sf.saxon.trans.Mode.applyTemplates(Mode.java:1124)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transformDocument(Controller.java:2106)
    at net.sf.saxon.Controller.transform(Controller.java:1705)
    at net.sf.saxon.s9api.XsltTransformer.transform(XsltTransformer.java:547)
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:177)
    at com.s1a.alpha.APP2.main(APP2.java:74)
```

And I've changed my output methon to `xml`, initially it was `html`. And toi my surprise, there is no Exception and the file is generated. I'm curious to know, how and why this failed with `html` and successful with `xml`

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the `xsl:value-of on line 314` that is the source of the error? Thanks!

Comment: @TimC ` <xsl:non-matching-substring>
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>` in this block I've `<xsl:value-of select="."/>` in line 314

Answer (score 0):

See https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#html-output, it requires

> Certain characters, specifically the control characters #x7F-#x9F, are
>   legal in XML but not in HTML. It is a serialization error
>   [err:SERE0014] to use the HTML output method when such characters
>   appear in the instance of the data model. The serializer MUST signal
>   the error.

Decimal 157 is hexadecimal 9D, so it is in that range.

Answer (score 0):

When characters in the range x80-x9f appear in your input, it usually means that the file is in Windows-1252 encoding but has been mislabelled as ISO-8859-1. However, I'm a little surprised to see x9D causing the trouble, since this is unassigned in Windows-1252. What character do you think it is supposed to be?

Note that the rule cited by @MartinHonnen is relaxed for XSLT 3.0 if you specify HTML version 5.0 as the output method. However, that doesn't alter the fact that there's something wrong with your input if it contains such characters.

Note also that characters in this range are not allowed in XML 1.0, but they are allowed in XML 1.1. You haven't given us enough information to see how this rogue character got into the system.

Comment: Hi @Michael Kay, I changed the HTML version to 5.0 and it worked fine. But I'm eager to know what have had gone in the backend.